# Outlook enable all macros what security risk is exactly

Tags: vba, security, outlook

I am following  [next example](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1107-outlook-auto-bcc.html), where custom macros was written to automatically BCC all outgoing email. 
To make it work, they set up setting to *"Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)"*.

Can someone explain what security risk is exactly? 
I do understand that I am granting permission to run unsigned code, but where this code can come? Will it search for code in emails or what? My current understanding is that VBA code can be only local, so someone needs to have local access to machine, what should be pretty safe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code is located locally. But someone can replace your code with anything else (malicious) - it can be another script or virus.

Comment: Is this the only concern or something else?